# Android Calendar View

Tags: android, calendar

У меня задача сделать календарь в котором можно выбирать только некоторые определенные даты (их нужно как то подсвечивать). Подскажите как это можно сделать в CalendarView. Или если это нельзя сделать в стандартном календаре, то есть ли для этого какая нибудь сторонняя библиотека?

Comment: https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview